# Getting Forbidden message when try to generate the bearer authentication token using Restassured lib

Tags: authentication, rest-assured, bearer-token

I'm trying Restassured library to generate the bearer authentication token. But getting the below in the console, though I'm using authorization in the header to run this snippet. Interestingly, the test run status is PASSSED for this but still unable to generate the token due to forbidden message.

`{ "message": "Forbidden" }`

Below is the code snippet which I've tried

```
RestAssured.baseURI="<endpoint URI>";
          Response response = RestAssured.given().
                  contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").
          headers("authorization","Basic <String value>).
          formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials").
          formParam("client_id", "<String value>").
          formParam("scope", "<String value>").
          when().post();
          response.prettyPrint();
```